# When dealing cards, they aren't showing up as different cards. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can't seem to get my cards to show up as different cards.  I don't know what I am doing wrong in my code.

output:

```
playerOne has played: 6 of Hearts | PlayerTwo has played: 9 of Clubs
PlayerTwo Wins!
playerOne has played: 6 of Hearts | PlayerTwo has played: 9 of Clubs
PlayerTwo Wins!
playerOne has played: 6 of Hearts | PlayerTwo has played: 9 of Clubs
```

---

expected output:

```
playerOne has played: 7 of Hearts | PlayerTwo has played: 9 of Clubs
PlayerTwo Wins!
playerOne has played: 3 of Diamonds | PlayerTwo has played: 6 of Hearts
PlayerTwo Wins!
playerOne has played: 2 of Clubs | PlayerTwo has played: 5 of Spades
```

---

```
random.shuffle(deck)
for play in deck:
    firstHalf = play[0:int(52/2)]
    secondHalf = play[int(52/2):]
    for c,c2 in zip(firstHalf, secondHalf):
        a = c["value"]
        x = c["suit"]
        b = c2["value"]
        y = c2["suit"]
        print(playerOne + " has played: " + str(a) + " of " +  x + " | " + playerTwo + " has played: " + str(b) + " of " + y)
        if a > b:
            print(playerOne + " Wins! ")
        elif a < b:
            print(playerTwo + " Wins! ")
        else:
            print("This is WAR!")
```

Comment: The values of `a`, `b`, `x`, and `y` do not change in the last loop. As a side note, `int(52/2)` is `52//2`.

Comment: you have 3 loops. the first 2 loops run to completion and assign values to `a,b,x and y` before you hit your 3rd loop. The code works as you wrote it, but does not do what you would have liked it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try with this instead:

```
random.shuffle(deck)
for play in deck:
    firstHalf = play[0:int(52/2)]
    secondHalf = play[int(52/2):]
    for c,c2 in zip(firstHalf, secondHalf):
        a = c["value"]
        x = c["suit"]
        b = c2["value"]
        y = c2["suit"]
        print(playerOne + " has played: " + str(a) + " of " +  x + " | " + playerTwo + " has played: " + str(b) + " of " + y)
        if a > b:
            print(playerOne + " Wins! ")
        elif a < b:
            print(playerTwo + " Wins! ")
        else:
            print("This is WAR!")
```

Not quite sure what you are trying to do with `for play in deck`, but you want to update your variables within the loop, which is the whole point of looping in this case after all.

Comment: Glad it did. Please don't forget to set as correct if it did :-)

Comment: think you can help me with something else?

Answer (score 0):

You're running the loop through the two halves of the deck without saving the results anywhere. So `a, x, b, y` are constant, and equal to the last "card" dealt in those two first for-loops.
Maybe try running through the cards "while playing":

```
random.shuffle(deck)
firstHalf = deck[0:int(52/2)]
secondHalf = deck[int(52/2):]
for i in range(26):
    a = firstHalf[i]["value"]
    x = firstHalf[i]["suit"]
    b = secondHalf[i]["value"]
    y = secondHalf[i]["suit"]      
    print(playerOne + " has played: " + str(a) + " of " +  x + " | " + playerTwo + " has played: " + str(b) + " of " + y)
    if a > b:
      print(playerOne + " Wins! ")
    elif a < b:
      print(playerTwo + " Wins! ")
    else:
      print("This is WAR!")
```

I can't promise my code runs, because your example isn't minimally "runnable", but you get the gist.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can `zip` the two halves of the deck and iterate through them instead:

```
random.shuffle(deck)
firstHalf = deck[0:int(52/2)]
secondHalf = deck[int(52/2):]
for d1, d2 in zip(firstHalf, secondHalf):
    v1, v2 = d1['value'], d2['value']
    print(playerOne + " has played: " + str(v1) + " of " +  d1['suit'] + " | " + playerTwo + " has played: " + str(v1) + " of " + d2['suit'])
    if v1 > v2:
      print(playerOne + " Wins! ")
    elif v1 < v2:
      print(playerTwo + " Wins! ")
    else:
      print("This is WAR!")
```

Comment: what does the term zip mean in python 3?

Comment: `zip` is a built-in function that iterates through all of the given sequences together and takes one item from each sequence to yield a tuple in each iteration, so that `zip('ABC', 'xyz')` generates a sequence of `'Ax', 'By', 'Cz'`, for example. See https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip for details.